# how to delete x instances of y element in a list in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

I have a list, and in that list, I have a lot of duplicated values. This is the format of the list:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECxFI.jpg

So I have some fields, in this order: "User_ID" "Movie_ID" "Rating" "Time"

What I want to do is, remove, from the 5th occurrence of "User_ID" untill I find a differente "User_ID". For example:

Let's suppose that I have a list with only "User_ID" (from 1 - 196) like this:

1, 1, 1 ,1 ,1, 1, 2 ,2 , 2, 2, 2, 2, 2...

In this case, I have six occurrences of number 1 and seven occurrences of number 2.

So, I will remove, from 1, after the fifth occurrence, until I find the first "2". And the same thing for 2: I will start removing after its fifth occurrence, untill I find a new number, which will be "3", and so on.

So, I will get a new list, like this: 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2
containing only 5 instances of each different element.

I know I can acess all the "User_ID" field like this: `list[index]["User_ID"]`

is there a function that does that? Or if there isn't, could someone help me to create one?

Thanks for the help!

What I was trying to do was something like this:

```
a = 0
b = 1
start = 0
position = 0

while(something that I don't know):
    while(list[a]['User_ID'] == list[b]['User_ID']): #iterate through the list, and I only advance to the next elements if the previous and next elements are the same
        a+=1
        b+=1
        position+=1 
    if(list[a]['User_ID'] != list[b]['User_ID']): #when I finally find a different element
        del new_list[start:start+position] #I delete from the start position, which is five untill the position before the different element.
        a+=1
        b+=1
        start+=5
```

Comment: Post all relevant data here directly as text. Also, what have you tried? What specifically do you need help with?

Comment: Is this list sorted by user_id and if not, do you want only adjacent duplicates beyond 5 removed or any duplicates beyond 5?

Comment: It is sorted by user_id. I would like to remove all duplicates beyond 5 occurences

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input seems to be a `list` of `dict` instances. You can use various [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) to only keep 5 dicts with same `User_ID` key in a space and time efficient manner:

```
from itertools import chain, groupby, islice
from operator import itemgetter

lst = [{'User_ID': 1, ...}, {'User_ID': 1, ...}, ..., {'User_ID': 2, ...}, ...]    

key = itemgetter('User_ID')
only5 = list(chain.from_iterable(islice(g, 5) for _, g in groupby(lst, key=key)))
```

This groups the list into chunks with the same `User_ID` and then takes the first `5` from each chunk into the new list.

Comment: That was exacly what I wanted, thanks! As you said, it was indeed a list of dict instances. But I didn't understand exactly how this code works. For example, in this line `only5 = list(chain.from_iterable(islice(g, 5) for _, g in groupby(lst, key=key)))` There is this `for_,g in groupy (lst,key=key)`, how does that work?

Comment: I would have to refer you to the docs that I linked. You should also just play around with all these functions on the interactive interpreter to see what they are actually doing ;) however, `groupby` returns an iterator over pairs `(k, g)` where `k` is the result of the `key` function (applied to the list elements) and `g` is an iterator over the group of elements with the same key results. Since this line only makes use of the groups, the keys are "discarded" to the "anonymous" `_` variable in the generator expression.

Answer (score 1):

```
list=[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3]
unique=set(list)

for x in unique:
   y=list.count(x)
   while y>5:
       list.remove(x)
       y-=1

print(list)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am mostly confused by your list of `[1,1,1,1,1]` etc, it looks like you have a list of dicts or objects.

If you care about every field you can probably just make it a set then back into a list: 
`my_list = list(set(my_list))`

if they are objects, you can override `__eq__(self,other)` and `__hash__(self)` and I think you will be able to use the same list/set/list transform to remove duplicates.